# Finding specific words in a file

Tags: python

I have to write a program in python where the user is given a menu with four different "word games". There is a file called dictionary.txt and one of the games requires the user to input a) the number of letters in a word and b) a letter to exclude from the words being searched in the dictionary (dictionary.txt has the whole dictionary). Then the program prints the words that follow the user's requirements. My question is how on earth do I open the file and search for words with a certain length in that file. I only have a basic code which only asks the user for inputs. I'm am very new at this please help :(
this is what I have up to the first option. The others are fine and I know how to break the loop but this specific one is really giving me trouble. I have tried everything and I just keep getting errors. Honestly, I only took this class because someone said it would be fun. It is, but recently I've really been falling behind and I have no idea what to do now. This is an intro level course so please be nice I've never done this before until now :(

```
print
print "Choose Which Game You Want to Play"
print "a) Find words with only one vowel and excluding a specific letter."
print "b) Find words containing all but one of a set of letters."
print "c) Find words containing a specific character string."
print "d) Find words containing state abbreviations."
print "e) Find US state capitals that start with months."
print "q) Quit."
print

choice = raw_input("Enter a choice: ")
choice = choice.lower()
print choice

while choice != "q":
    if choice == "a":
        #wordlen = word length user is looking for.s

        wordlen = raw_input("Please enter the word length you are looking for: ")
        wordlen = int(wordlen)
        print wordlen

        #letterex = letter user wishes to exclude.
        letterex = raw_input("Please enter the letter you'd like to exclude: ")
        letterex = letterex.lower()
        print letterex
```

Comment: 1. Is this homework? If so, please tag as such.
2. Show us the code you have already.
3. Have you tried *anything* yet?

Comment: Also, please break your question up into paragraphs. Without line-breaks, your question assumes a "wall of text" appearance that makes it very hard to read. (Communication skills, yo!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the file, use [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open). You should also read the Python tutorial sec. 7, [file input/output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

**Open a file and get each line**

Assuming your `dictionary.txt` has each word on a separate line:

```
opened_file = open('dictionary.txt')
for line in opened_file:
    print(line) # Put your code here to run it for each word in the dictionary
```

**Word length:**

You can check the length of a string using its `str.len()` method. See the [Python documentation on string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
"Bacon, eggs and spam".len() # returns '20' for 20 characters long
```

**Check if a letter is in a word:**

Use `str.find()`, again from the Python sring methods.

---

Further comments after seeing your code sample:

- If you want to print a multi-line prompt, use the [heredoc syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Python) (triple quotes) instead of repeated `print()` statements.
- What happens if, when asked "how many letters long", your user enters `bacon sandwich` instead of a number? (Your assignment may not *specify* that you should gracefully handle incorrect user input, but it never hurts to *think* about it.)

Comment: @KimY : No worries. Incidentally, the way to show appreciation on StackOverflow is by *upvoting* answers you found helpful, and *accepting* the answer you think best answered your question.

Comment: ohhhhh sorry haha i just joined so i had no idea about that stuff until today

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you'd want to do, algorithmically:

1. Open up your file
2. Read it line by line, and on each line (assuming each line has one and only one word), check if that word is a) of appropriate length and b) does not contain the excluded character

What sort of control flow would this suggest you use? Think about it.

I'm not sure if you're confused about how to approach this from a problem-solving standpoint or a Python standpoint, but if you're not sure how to do this specifically in Python, here are some helpful links:

- [The Input and Output section of the official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- [The `len()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len), which can be used to get the length of a string, list, set, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how on earth do I open the file

Use the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

```
with open('dictionary.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
       print line
```

> and search for words with a certain length in that file.

First, decide what is the length of the word you want to search.

Then, read each line of the file that has the words.

Check each word for its length.

If it matches the length you are looking for, add it to a list.